# Wordpress: echo TOTAL amount of posts for post author by meta_key?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok, so I know how to echo meta_key value for a post:

```
<?php 
$meta_print_value=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_heart_this',true);
echo($meta_print_value);
?>
```

I also know how to echo a TOTAL amount of posts with this specific meta_key:

```
<?php  $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_heart_this' ) ) 
echo $query->found_posts; ?>
```

What I need, is the TOTAL amount of posts for this meta_key for a post author.

I know I need to add `get_the_author()` somewhere in the above code to show the total amount of posts for the post author only, but struggling for a while now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Author Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters) in WP_Query(). You can use author id/name/multiple authors. For your case, the query should look like this:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'author' => get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
        'meta_key' => '_heart_this',
    ),
 );
echo $query->found_posts; ?>
```